# Change default selection for "Embed or Link"?

Tags: attachments

I want the default ATTACHMENT DISPLAY SETTINGS for media files (not images) to be set to "Link to Media File". I have found update_option snippets for images, but not audio/video. Can't find the media equivalent of 'image_default_link_type' for media to set the pre-selected option. Any help? Much appreciated.